# publish extjs 6 application using sencha cmd

Tags: extjs, extjs6, sencha-cmd

I build an app in extjs 6 using sencha cmd and I try this command:

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/sdk generate app MyApp ./
```

but its folder has a massive size on disk(about 150MB), how can i remove unnecessary files and publish the app on a server(probably using sencha cmd)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is quite normal that your development environment will be large, and the deployment process will only use what is needed and minify it to make the deployed code much smaller

Comment: What kind of disk are we talking about, that 150MB is considered to be "massive size"? Or is that a typo and really should read "150GB"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For development environment 150 MB is fine. The folder size is big because by default sencha cmd copies the framework code in the project directory.

It is not recommended to put this all files into final build.

Sencha cmd provides another useful command

```
sencha app build
```

which will generate the **minified production build** in **build** folder which is smaller and considered as code to publish.

To generate development, **build without minified code** you can try following command:

```
sencha app build development
```

You can find more featuers provided by sencha cmd at : http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/extjs/cmd_app.html